# Is it possible to connect redux store and use it at the top level element - App.tsx?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

in my application at start up I have a splash screen. While splash is shown I retrieve some data using `asyncStorage`. I want to save that data to my store. So I connected my `App.ts` component to the store as such:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => ({
  setTokenValidity: (isTokenValid:boolean) => dispatch(setTokenValidity(isTokenValid))
})

const mapStateToProps = (state:any) => ({
  isTokenValid: state.isTokenValid
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

This is the rest of the setup of `App.ts`:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
let userToken = null;

const App = (props:any) => {

  const [IsSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {

    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      try {
        userToken = await retrieveData('Token',null);    
        SplashScreen.hide();

        if(userToken != null) {
          setIsSignedIn(true);
          props.setTokenValidity(true)
        }

      } catch (e) {
        // Restoring token failed
      }
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <Provider store={storeFactory()}>
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator >
    {!props.isTokenValid ? (
      <>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown:false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown:false }}/>
      </>
      
      ) : (
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown:false }}/>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator >  
  </NavigationContainer>
  </Provider>
  );
};
```

When I run the application I get an error stating:

`Could not find "store" in the context of "Conenct(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider> or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.`

My question is, is it possible to connect to the store at this top level or it can only be done in the sub components?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, *it can only be done in the sub components* in your case. To use connect on `App`, you'll need to move the `<Provider>` element one level up in the hierarchy. Usually, you'd have some sort of `<Root>` element which takes care of setting up the store and then `App` as a descendant of it.